# For the same operator, when I use qiskit's VQE and QAOA solutions, the results are completely different

Tags: qiskit, vqe, qaoa

Specifically, I can't get the correct result using QAOA，A total of 6 qubits were used in this work，this is part of my code using VQE and QAOA
localsim = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

```
optimizer = SPSA(max_trials=500)
ansatz = TwoLocal(rotation_blocks='ry', entanglement_blocks='cz')
vqe = VQE(op, ansatz, optimizer = optimizer)
results1 = vqe.run(localsim)
```

and

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter = 100)
depth = 10
initial = QuantumCircuit(nbr_qubits)
qaoa = QAOA(operator=op, optimizer=optimizer, p = depth,initial_state = initial, quantum_instance=localsim)
results2 = qaoa.run()
```

I tried changing depth and optimizer type but it didn't work，The following two pictures are the results of VQE and QAOA respectively
[image]

[image]

Is it because I'm using QAOA incorrectly?

Comment: What was your operator?

Comment: op is an ising hamiltonian

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use the new released version, but you can still plot out iteration with graph and compare them, see what happen. choose of optimizer, depth, max iteration will effect the result.
reference: https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/simulating-molecules-using-vqe